# How to get Banks have High Number of branches first to Low Number of Branch after that In Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am Using Laravel Relation for listing My branches of bank and hierarchy of all this setup is like below

> Country--hasMany->Banks--hasMany->Branches.

```
 $country = Country::where("iso2",  $this->app->request->route()->parameter('country'))->first();
```

Here is The relation code for banks in the country model:

```
public function banks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Bank::class);
}
```

and branch Relation code in Bank Model

```
 public function branches()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Branch::class);
}
```

Now my motive is that I want to get only 15 banks from this country veriable but the condition is that the banks which have high number of branches will get first in the list.
Can you provide me any simple solution with laravel eloquent queries it would be a great help for me.

Comment: Edit and post your `query` code with your question, so that we can edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys for the solution of this I use withCount and here is my solution query

```
 $banks = Bank::where('country_id', $country->id)->withCount('branches')->having('branches_count', '>', 0)->orderBy('branches_count', 'DESC')->take(15)->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$banks = Bank::with(['branches'])
->map(function ($bank) {
    $bank->num_branches = $bank->branches->count();
    $bank;
})
->sortByDesc('num_branches')
->take(15);
```